# Any data about Mobile Phone Contacts?

Tags: data-request, telecom

I am going to do some analytics on Mobile Phone Contacts data, in particular, I would like to find the average number of contacts, to determine social groups(family, friends, сolleagues), but I didn't find anything on the web :(
I need it for my master's thesis
Maybe anyone could help me and suggest open sources where I can get this data?

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for Calling Detail Record(CDR) dataset to my research of link prediction. Recently, I found a telecom dataset from the link:http://theodi.fbk.eu/openbigdata/. Maybe it will give you some help.